# dynnamically created textbox row value not passing correctly in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, post

I am creating Laravel Application , it has a page , in that row added dynamically and delete option  available each row and also i need to calculate the total for points , it works perfectly, but the problem was unable to post the textbox values using post,
only empty arrays was shown, any help will be appriciated, thanks in advance...

The colmns are meter,defects,points

points ->calculated at same page , works well,

problem was the 'defects' not show values when submit the data,

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#add').click(function(){
        addRow('t')
    })
});
function keyup() {
          $(this).closest('tr').find('.tot');
    calculateSum();
}
function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values  
    $(".tot").each(function () {
        //add only if the value is number  
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places  
    $("#sum").val(sum.toFixed(2));
}
function addRow(tableID) {
    //      alert(text+id);  
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0); //chekbox  
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    element1.type = "checkbox";
    element1.setAttribute('style', 'width: 47px');
    cell1.appendChild(element1);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1); //item  
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");
    element2.type = "text";
    element2.setAttribute("name","meter[]");  
    element2.setAttribute('style', 'width: 175px');
   // element2.setAttribute("value", "test");
    cell2.appendChild(element2);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2); //price  
    var element3 = document.createElement("input");
    element3.type = "text";
    element2.setAttribute("name","defects[]");  
    cell3.appendChild(element3);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3); //qty  
    var element4 = document.createElement("input");
    element4.type = "text";
    element4.setAttribute("class", "tot");
    cell4.appendChild(element4);
    $(element4).keyup(keyup)       
}
```

```
<TABLE id="dataTable" width="60%" border="1"> 
   <tr><TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD> 
        <TD> 1 </TD> 
        <TD> <INPUT type="defects[]"  class="txt"/> </TD> </tr>
</TABLE>
<INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" /> 
<INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
```

Comment: can you provide a demo in snippet or fiddle?

Comment: Try with the $.clone option provided by the jquery.

Comment: i am new for jquery , how to use this

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>
    function addRow(tableID) {

        var szTr;
        szTr = '<tr><TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD><TD> 1 </TD>       <TD> <INPUT type="defects[]"  class="txt"/></TD> </tr>'
        $('#' + tableID + ' tbody').append(szTr)
    }
    function CalculateSum() {
        var iTotal = 0;
        $('#dataTable tbody tr').find('td :input').each(function () {
            if (!isNaN($(this).val()) && $.trim($(this).val())!="") {
                iTotal = iTotal + parseInt($(this).val(), 10)
            }

        });
        alert(iTotal)
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {



    });
</script>
</head>
<body>


  <TABLE id="dataTable" width="60%" border="1"> 
      <tbody>
     <tr><TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD> 
        <TD> 1 </TD> 
        <TD> <INPUT type="defects[]"  class="txt"/></TD> </tr>
          </tbody>
</TABLE>


<INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable');" /> 
<INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable');" /> 

<INPUT type="button" value="Sum" onclick="CalculateSum();" /> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when i input data first text box it calculates sum correctly , when i leave first box and input give second text box it creates 'Nan' Error